# Different IP Subnets in VM and on Host

Tags: windows, networking, server, virtualbox, vmware

this is my first Post here. Please be gentle :)

I have the following Problem:

I have a Windows Server 2k8 Installation hosted somewhere, and now i wanted to run an VirtualBox Guest on this Server and give it its own public IP. I asked my Server-Provider for an Extra IP which I got. Now this IP is in a totally different Network...

The Host System has this IP Address:

```
85.x.x.x / 28
```

and the Guest System should have this IP:

```
123.x.x.x / 28
```

Now my Question is:
Can i give this VM the Second IP and let it be publically accessible, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in control of everything where you host it, say on a machine in your home.

Open oraclebox, go to your vm, right click go to settings -> Network, and set it to NAT. (assuming your IP is in the same subnet of the host)

Add the IP to you DNS server
Start the vm and change the ip. 
That should cover your issue.